# Autoclick script triggered by something

Tags: javascript

Hello i would like to know if it's possible to create a script that would click on a button if a particular element appears on a particular position on the page, the click would be triggered by the element appearing on a definite position

Comment: Yes, it's possible

Comment: now i have a question too: why??!?

Comment: Can someone show me the code for it ?